# Click on image from css_selector on selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I have a below code.
I need to click on image up.gif only for hidebutton2.
How can this be possible using selenium -python
Below is a source code from css_selector

```
    <IMG onclick=hidePackage() id=hideButton2 style="BORDER-TOP: #ff0000 1px solid; BORDER-RIGHT: #ff0000 1px solid; BORDER-BOTTOM: #ff0000 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT: #ff0000 1px solid; DISPLAY: block" src="../../scripts/jQueryFramework/plugins/jqGrid/themes/steel/images/up.gif">
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way for you to interact with this element would be:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("hideButton2").click()
```

UPDATE:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#hideButton2").click()
```

Comment: Yes I tried the way but its not working.Can you tell me how to do this with find_element_by_cssseslector

Comment: Ok css_selector is also not working.Actually in GUI I have a horizontal line and after click on it it will expand or collapse.So I think I need another approach to click on it.

Comment: <IMG onclick=showPackageDetails(this) id="ALPHA PACKAGE_Show_Id" style="BORDER-TOP: #ff0000 1px solid; BORDER-RIGHT: #ff0000 1px solid; BORDER-BOTTOM: #ff0000 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT: #ff0000 1px solid" src="https:/www.aaa.com/jQueryFramework/plugins/jqGrid/themes/steel/images/down.gif">                                                         How to click on above code by css_selector

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#ALPHA PACKAGE_Show_Id").click()` would be how to click on that line you're mentioning. In case you hadn't noticed, an `ID` tag is referenced with `#` for css selectors.

Comment: Thanks Mark. The code that I have provided is from the horizontal bar on the GUI and at the end of that bar a down.gif is attached and using this code I am not able to click on that bar. I tried to upload the snapshot but due to some issue with this website like 10 impressiosn , I am not able to upload it. Can you please suggest how to click that down.gif

Comment: The code you provided within the `img` tag shows a file name for the `down.gif`, clicking on the webelement with that id will be clicking on that element. I can't really see how you're not getting the result you want.

Comment: Due to 10 reputation, I am not able to post my snapshot. I tried below things using xapth and it failed::::::::::[Dbg]>>> menu = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//img[@id='ALPHA PACKAGE_Show_Id']")
[Dbg]>>> print menu
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x01828270>]
[Dbg]>>> menu = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//img[@id='ALPHA PACKAGE_Show_Id']").click()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
[Dbg]>>>

Comment: You're using `find_elements_` which returns a list, use `find_element_` instead.